# Есть List  , как его корректно вывести в DataGrid или ListView?

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf, binding

Импортирую из текстового файла с разделителями строки, значения которых потом конвертятся в double.

```
var List<double[]> inData = new List<double[]>();
var line = reader.ReadLine();
if (line != null)
{
    var elements = line.Split(separator);
    if (elements.Length!=0)
    {
        double[] converted = ToDoubleFromString(elements); //конверчу из строки в дабл
        if (converted != null) inData.Add(converted);       
    }    
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = inData;
}
```

При попытке указания DataGrid1.ItemsSource значения в датагрид не выводятся, а выводится информация о структуре массива. Как вывести сами значения? Пробовал перевести в матрицу double[,] , но ее тоже не отображает DataGrid.

Comment: Потому что элементами листа являются массивы! В случае листа такого вида: List<double> все выведется без доп усилий.

Comment: ну так у меня массив массивов как бы, а не просто значений

Comment: Как его надо отображать, массив массивов? Все в один массив или с группировками или еще как то?

Comment: в датагрит , по типу: 
Column1      | Column2      | ColumnN
inData[0][0] | inData[0][1] | inData[0][2]
inData[1][0] | inData[1][1] | inData[1][2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, вам нужен не массив массивов, а массив экземпляров класса. `DataGrid` сам по себе не догадается, что означают ваши данные! Он [предполагает](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx), что его ItemsSource -- IEnumerable<> (в частности, List<> подойдёт) экземпляров какого-то фиксированного класса, и для нас же лучше, чтобы его предположение оправдалось. Далее, в классе вместо полей должны быть открытые свойства:

```
class DataEntry
{
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public double Velocity { get; set; }
    public double Geschwindigkeit { get; set; }
    public double Vitesse { get; set; }
    public double Rapidez { get; set; }
}

public List<DataEntry> ItemsSource { get; set; }
```

Так должно уже работать на отображение.

Если же вы хотите также ловить изменения в ItemsSource, вам необходимо перейти от List<> к ObservableCollection, и реализовать INotifyPropertyChange в `DataEntry`.

Comment: соль в том, что я заранее не знаю, сколько будет значений в строке и привести это к определенному классу не представляется возможным.

Comment: @fundottz: хм. а сколько колонок должно получиться? их число должно меняться при добавлении нового элемента в список?

Comment: количество элементов в строке не известно, в каждой строке оно может быть разным, элементы строки - это double[], каждый массив значений из строки является элементом List<double[]> inData

Comment: @fundottz: может, в таком случае вот это поможет: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5806/Binding-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-DataGrid ?

Comment: то , что надо! Спасибо!